# Creating a Script Extender

Tags: c++, hook

I'd like to create a script extender in C/C++ for a small game, very similar to the [Skyrim Script Extender](http://skse.silverlock.org/) and [FalloutNV Script Extender](http://nvse.silverlock.org/), in the sense that it hooks scripting commands from the games own language and adds functionality to them or even entirely new methods.

Unfortunately I have no idea where to start. Does anyone know of anywhere I can go or anything I can Google that will help me learn? I've tried reading the source code of the aforementioned programs but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these tools that allow games to be extended work more-or-less like a computer virus. They modify the original code in order to inject their own, except the code does nice things like give your character better armor instead of mean things like wrecking your computer. But, in principal, the techniques used are *identical*.

Unfortunately, explaining in detail how to write a computer virus would pretty clearly violate stack overflow's terms of service. Even modding itself can have questionable legal issues.

**Reverse Engineering Legal Issues FAQ:**
https://www.eff.org/issues/coders/reverse-engineering-faq

But, I can give you some generalities to point you in the right direction hopefully without getting banned.

Modifying someone else's compiled software is basically the art of debugging object code. If you can understand what the code does then you can change what the code does. **So the very, very best place to start is by reading the documentation for your C debugger.** As part of learning your debugger, you should also learn assembly code. You don't need to be an expert in it but you'll need to know the basics. If you can truly master your debugger, the rest is cake.

So, without further ado...

---

### The Modder's Banned Reading List

Shim (computing):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)

DLL Injection:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection

Dependency Walker:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker

Dynamic-Link Library Search Order:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

PE file format: (Windows)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Microsoft PE and COFF Specification:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx

ELF file format: (Linux, some game consoles and coin-ops)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Name Mangling:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Some Reasons Not to Do Anything Scary in Your DllMain: (except in your case...)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx

GetProcAddress function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Manually Walking a Stack:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/hardware/ff552143(v=vs.85).aspx

Debugging Tools for Windows (DDK):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx

Memory Window: (view memory contents)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e(v=vs.120).aspx

Alternatively to using dlls to get into the address space...

Buffer Overflow: (more for jailbreaking ROMs than software these days)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Instruction Relocation: ("old school")
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29

Rebasing: ("old school")
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebasing

---

### Accessibility API

**I'd like to recommend a clean, legal, albeit much more limited alternative: the accessibility hooks. Implementing accessibility features can be accomplished by any competent programmer with no voodoo or wizardry.**

Windows Accessibility API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Android Accessibility Service:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Accessibility features are "hooks" placed by the operating system that allow disabled users, such as the blind or the paralyzed, to use tools that "mod" software generically. This is in order to add features like screen readers that read the UI out loud since the user can't see.

While the hooks are intended specifically for responding to things like button presses, you can abuse these in lots of creative ways. For example, you could create an accessibility hook that added hotkeys to a program that didn't have a built-in hotkeys feature.

Accessibility hooks are the cleanest and most responsible way in. It doesn't require modifying the program binary and the accessibility hooks are *intended* to allow you to change the behavior of the software. Most importantly, accessibility hooks when used as designed do *not* require reverse engineering the original software nor violating the EULA.

However, there are limitations. Some (many) games draw directly to the screen without back-ending the buttons though the operating system; or they directly access the hardware without passing through the mouse events, etc. The companies who are handicapped-aware will usually provide a mode to turn this off or an alternative. For example, AMD Cataylst will let you turn off the window dressing on the CCC control panel which lets it work with accessibility tools. Some games draw directly to the screen but signal the operating system with the button event and text labels so screen readers work anyway. While Valve does direct-access, they implemented their own closed-captioning. It's a code-quality thing. Unfortunately, many people don't think of the disabled. It really depends on the game.

So, if you can, use the accessibility features of your operating system *if* the game supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The techniques used by SKSE and related programs are unfortunately not simple and can be difficult to fully grasp so don't worry if you don't "get it" right away.  My very basic understanding is that it finds Skyrim's functions, methods and data in memory and modifies them as needed. In order for new code to be added the game's data structures and classes need to be reverse engineered from the disassembly and what debug information is left within the EXE.

Ultimately, the best source of information will be the source code itself. If you are really interested in learning how it is done I would approach the problem roughly as follows:

1. Quickly review all the SKSE classes and draw the class structure.
2. For each class get a basic understanding of what it is meant to do.
3. Find the starting point of SKSE and manually trace through the program's execution. By "manually trace" I mean to actually read the code and try to understand what it is doing.
4. Once you think you have a good understanding of the code try creating some test projects using the SKSE code.

Other options would be to look at the [Oblivion](http://obse.silverlock.org/) or [Morrowind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mwse/) script extenders which are more mature but use similar techniques. Another option if you have time is to review all of "ianpatt" and other SKSE developer forum topics in the official [Skyrim Mods forum](http://forums.bethsoft.com/forum/183-skyrim-mods/) as he discusses a variety of low level topics from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Both projects that you have mentioned are open-source, and their sources would be the best place to start. the scripting language you are trying to extend does change what needs to be done to some extent, those that are open source (like Lua, v8, etc) are far easier to extend than proprietary closed source languages (like SC2 galaxy script, or NWNScript).

You may also want to research into the game who's script you are trying to extend, as someone else may have already done the needed bits (like with NWNScript).

If you do fall into the worst case scenario, the best place to start is your assembler and debugging/reverse-engineering skills, using tools like OllyDBG or IDA.